# Suddenly conv.user.storage data is not persisting or acting in a strange way

Tags: actions-on-google

Conv.user.storage data is not persisting, when using an alpha tester account it resets every time.  When using the simulator the data goes back to some snapshot it took at some point and has some values associated with a previous session.

I know this is vague but I was wondering if anyone ever had this problem.

I'm guessing the most reliable solution is to just use Google sign in if you are in anyway depending on that conv.user.storage data, is that right?

Let me add this snippet from Response section in the simulator, here you can user storage in the middle of the game, then I close and start again and all the values change completely going to a previous set of values from some point in the past, but this same set of values appears no matter how many times I reset, how can user storage find some previous snapsnot of values like this?

Before:

```
 "userStorage": "{\"data\":{\"questionorder\":\"19,29,27,18,30,20,16,22,12,11,17,28,14,25,6,21,8,4,5,3,1,23,10,26,13,24,7,2,15\",\"thisquestionnum\":9,\"randmozier\":true,\"visited\":true,\"questioncode\":111,\"popularity\":50,\"population\":100,\"rounds\":1}}"
```

After:

```
"userStorage": "{\"data\":{\"questionorder\":\"5,20,13,18,6,19,12,9,1,21,11,10,22,25,24,8,14,3,16,17,7,26\" ,\"thisquestionnum\":4,\"randmozier\":true,\"visited\":true,\"questioncode\":111,\"popularity\":30,\"population\":100,\"rounds\":2}}"
```

What is weird about this is, no matter what user storage starts out at, it will return to the second "After" values if I restart the game -- nowhere in the code is this being set, it's a previous set of values from some point, how can this issue suddenly appear?

I have even reset the code back 1 month so it is not possible at all to choose up to 26 questions like is shown in "questionorder" above -- but still it returns to that second state of user storage which is impossible in the code as it is, this is some major error in actions-on-google library or something which has changed in the last few days, has anyone had this issue with conv.user.storage?

Comment: I've seen another report of something similar. Raising this issue with some Googlers directly. How long has this been happening for you?

Comment: It was working 3 days prior to this post June 23rd and I just noticed it a few hours before posting on June 26th.

The other thing is, when I test with alpha testers then it just doesn't persist conv.user.storage at all.  But testing with my test account, no matter what, even if I delete all code and replace it with conv.ask(`hello world`) then when stopping the game and restarting, it will populate user storage with the above variables which was from some session perhaps several days ago.

Comment: Is it possible I can follow the report you mentioned?

Comment: I'm seeing reports this has been fixed. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yeah I did get an email from support saying it was fixed and the problem is gone now.